# Android loadLabel giving very laggy/slow performance, any solutions?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm trying to create a launcher app in which I fetch all app names with loadLabel, but it's taking almost 3 second to load the names, and is very slow!!! I tried removing that text and now it works very fast! But I want app labels, Can we use any alternative method? Here's the code:

```
TextView label = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.label);
            Typeface tf_label = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/RobotoC-Regular.ttf");
            label.setTypeface(tf_label);
            label.setText(info.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                    .toString());
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `loadLabel`? Loading a type face from an asset every time you create a label also seems quite expensive unless the system is caching it for you.

Comment: opening the target resources and getstring is equally slow.

Answer (score 0):

similiar problem here. I load the list of all apps and add them to a recyclerview, i had to wait some seconds before it was loaded so i timed the loading time. What i noticed is that loading icons and labels with 70 apps i needed around 2.6 seconds to load the apps, without loading icons and label ... an astonishing 61ms! YEAH milliseconds!
For now i am using a temporary solution, i will probably improve it in the future. What i did is create a model object that loads labels and icons in a background thread.

```
public class AppModel {
    ComponentName componentName;

    Drawable icon = null;
    String appName = "";

    public AppModel(ComponentName componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }

    public void init(ActivityInfo ai, PackageManager pm) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                appName = (String) ai.loadLabel(pm);
                icon = ai.loadIcon(pm);
            }
        }).start();

    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

when i load the apps i do the following:

```
AppModel appModel = new AppModel(componentName);
appModel.init(ai, pm);
// other stuff
```

I needed a fast and working hotfix, in this way while the app is added to the recyclerview the labels and icons get loaded in background, cutting down the loading time by a lot!

A future solution i am considering is to load those icons and labels in multithreading.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sad to see they haven't improved the single method of loading label in years!